# Python sqlite how to alter table add columb if not exists

Tags: python, sqlite

I want: if column not exists, add column

```
def tablo_olustur():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+asin+"(Tarih TEXT)")
    con.commit()
tablo_olustur()

def veri_ekle(Satıcı_ismi,Stok_Miktarı):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+asin+' (Tarih, "{}") values (?,?)'.format(Satıcı_ismi),(currentDT,Stok_Miktarı))
    con.commit()

#def ver_ekle2(Stok_Miktarı):
#    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+asin+" (Satıcı_ismi, '{}') values (?,?)".format(currentDT),(Satıcı_ismi,Stok_Miktarı))
#    con.commit()

def sutun_ekle(sutun):
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE "+asin+' ADD COLUMN "{}" '.format(sutun))
    con.commit()
```

I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: xxxx` error from python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, if column exists it will add if not you can check if any column of same name already exists in the table

```
def sutun_ekle(sutun):
    try:
        cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE "+asin+' ADD COLUMN "{}" '.format(sutun))
        con.commit()
    except:
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(asin)")
        print cursor.fetchall() #prints the list of existing column header
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect your table to see whether the column exists:

```
# replace your_table with your table you want to inspect
existing_cols = [row.column_name for row in cursor.columns(table='your_table')

# check if the column you want to add is in the list
if col_add in existing_cols:
    pass  # do nothing
else:
    # alter table
    # replace your_table with the table you want to alter
    # replace varchar(32) with the data type for the column
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN {} varchar(32)".format(col_add)
    con.commit()
```